# Problems in JSON results calling JAWBONE API

Tags: java, android, jawbone

I'm developing an Android app to analyze the UP Band data.
Using the example given in the UP SDK for Android , at the moment I can get the trend data as a JSON object.
The problem is that this JSON object is malformed. 
In fact when I try to deserialize the Trend data with:

```
JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(o.toString());
```

I get the following error:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line ...

Moreover, inspecting the result of the API call I get:

{meta={user_xid=*MASKED*, message=OK, code=200.0, time=1.430319261E9}, data={earliest=2.0130408E7, data=[[2.0150423E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=8073.0, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=1336.0, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, m_steps=10760.0, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=0.0, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, s_awake_time=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=9660.0, m_active_time=5717.0, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=532.710151311, e_calories=null, bmr=1426.58256449, m_total_calories=1959.2927158, n_sound=null, e_sugar=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, s_asleep_time=null, s_duration=null, n_awake=null, age=69.8273972603, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=null, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null}], [2.0150424E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=9641.0, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=1145.0, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, m_steps=12657.0, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=0.0, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, s_awake_time=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=11460.0, m_active_time=6508.0, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=632.988689047, e_calories=null, bmr=1412.57952142, m_total_calories=2045.56821047, n_sound=null, e_sugar=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, s_asleep_time=null, s_duration=null, n_awake=null, age=69.8301369863, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=null, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null}], [2.0150425E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=21643.0, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=2455.0, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, e_calories=null, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=0.0, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, s_awake_time=null, s_sound=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=1860.0, m_active_time=14625.0, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=1422.11015205, bmr=1269.04654879, m_total_calories=2691.15670084, n_sound=null, s_asleep_time=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, e_sugar=null, s_duration=null, n_awake=null, age=69.8328767123, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, m_steps=28322.0, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null}], [2.0150426E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=1572.0, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=265.0, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, m_steps=2116.0, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=0.0, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, e_calories=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=6360.0, s_awake_time=null, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=104.843981181, bmr=1507.45521348, m_total_calories=1612.29919466, n_sound=null, s_asleep_time=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, e_sugar=null, s_duration=null, n_awake=null, age=69.8356164384, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=null, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null, m_active_time=1140.0}], [2.0150427E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=4334.0, s_awakenings=0.0, height=1.72, m_lcat=1091.0, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=0.0, m_steps=5726.0, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=0.0, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=0.0, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=-5400.0, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, s_awake_time=17100.0, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=4320.0, m_active_time=2978.0, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=283.00944155, e_calories=null, bmr=1474.94024527, m_total_calories=1757.94968682, n_sound=null, s_asleep_time=-5400.0, e_sodium=null, s_awake=0.0, e_sugar=null, s_duration=22500.0, n_awake=null, age=69.8383561644, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=0.0, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null}], [2.0150428E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=null, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=null, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, e_calories=null, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=null, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, m_steps=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=null, s_awake_time=null, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=null, bmr=1527.57418082, m_total_calories=1527.57418082, n_sound=null, s_asleep_time=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, e_sugar=null, s_duration=null, n_awake=null, age=69.8410958904, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=null, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, gender=0.0, n_asleep_time=null, m_active_time=null}], [2.0150429E7, {e_protein=null, weight=78.0, goal_body_weight_intent=null, body_fat=null, m_distance=null, s_awakenings=null, height=1.72, m_lcat=null, goal_body_weight=null, s_quality=null, m_steps=null, e_cholesterol=null, s_light=null, e_sat_fat=null, n_bedtime=null, m_workout_time=null, e_calcium=null, s_bedtime=null, n_awakenings=null, n_light=null, s_awake_time=null, pal=null, n_duration=null, m_lcit=null, m_active_time=null, e_unsat_fat=null, m_calories=null, e_calories=null, bmr=1527.55567397, m_total_calories=503.191690242, n_sound=null, s_asleep_time=null, e_sodium=null, s_awake=null, e_sugar=null, s_duration=null, gender=0.0, age=69.8438356164, e_carbs=null, e_fiber=null, s_sound=null, n_quality=null, n_awake_time=null, n_awake=null, n_asleep_time=null}]], links={next=/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/ymQeH-UUAU8hs54Ad7Mxjw/trends/?end_date=20150422&bucket_size=d&num_buckets=7}}}

The main problem in the previous JSON object is that the keys aren't well formed. In fact they should be strings of characters between "".
Could you please give me some indication on how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot for your help.
[EDIT]

This the callback function I was starting to modify to get the data from Jawbone:

```
private Callback genericCallbackListener = new Callback<Object>() {
@Override
public void success(Object o, Response response) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,  "api call successful, json output: " + o.toString());
//I added the following 3 lines of code to parse the JSON result
    JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(o.toString());
    JsonObject root = je.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement je2 = root.get("Data");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), je2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,  "api call failed, error message: " + retrofitError.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), retrofitError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

};

Comment: string you are trying to parse is not a valid json string

Comment: All the keys should be strings in quotes, but all of your keys are just strings without any wrapping, so it's not valid json. Try use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @dit this is the problem. But what is the solution? It seems that Jawbone sdk give back a malformed JSON object and I don't know how to fix it :)

Comment: @Dmitry Ginzburg, It is true. The keys are malformed. I wonder if there is some option in the retrofit library, used by Jawbone sdk, to solve it.

Comment: it's time to show us some code. How do you get the json from the server?

Comment: @dit I used the Jawbone Android SDK. I added few lines to the callback function to parse the JSON. I added the code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I believe I know what your problem is. You are using retrofit `Callback` wrong.

You do not need to parse the result. Jawbone + [retrofit](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests/) will do it for you.

Check this example:

```
public interface BookService{
    @GET("/books")
    void getBooks(Callback<List<Book>> books);
}

// AND THEN

private Callback genericCallbackListener = new Callback<List<Book>>() {

    @Override
    public void success(List<Book> books, Response response) {
        [...] // use books
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

    }
}

taskService.getBooks(genericCallbackListener);
```

So do not try manually to parse the response. Let *Jawbone Android SDK* do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I should write a POJO class, List<Book> in your example, to get Jawbone and retrofit work for me. Isn't it?